# Does clang support auto parallelization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, clang

Most modern C++ compilers (gcc, Intel, MS) support both autoparallelization and autovectorization when used with the maximum optimization switch.

Does clang support automatic parallelization or not? If it does how it is enabled and where is the documentation? I have done many google searches without being able to find something specific, except for support for autovectorization with the -03 switch.

Comment: You can always try it out for yourself, e.g. on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/).

Comment: I can not see in the generated assembly autoparallelization happening in gcc with -O3 plus the switches for autoparallelization in godbolt. Infact i see zero changes in the generated assembly at all. In clang i do not believe there are autoparallelization switches at all. That is what i am looking for. Autovectorization is happening from -O2 and up in both.

Comment: Updated Note: gcc up to 5.4 produces autoparallelization by using openmp to parallelize under the hood. gcc 6.1 and 6.2 do not produce autoparallelization code. It seems autoparallelization is dropped or simply not supported anymore somewhere around 6.x version but it is not mentioned in the gcc documentation. More info would be great.